# What does the RAT flag mean?

Tags: kerberos

I do this command: `klist -c -f`

And I get next result:

```
Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
29.10.2019 15:40:04  29.10.2019 16:40:04  HTTP:/principal@host
        renew until 05.11.2019 16:37:41  Flags: RAT
```

What does the *RAT* flag mean? Can't find it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like answer you should looking for is

R - Renewable ,

A - preAuthenticated ,

T - Transit policy checked.

source : 
https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/user/user_commands/klist.html